# SQL to Relation Algebra

Tags: sql, oracle, algebra, relational-algebra

How can I white this in relation algebra? I'm always getting confused with those GROUP BY and HAVING COUNT...Can't really formulate that.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Name
FROM studies, course
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(course_id) FROM studies
GROUP BY course_id HAVING COUNT (course_id) > 1) >= 2
AND (SELECT course_id FROM studies
GROUP BY course_id HAVING COUNT (course_id) > 1) = course.course_id;
```

Comment: This would be easier to understand if you could provide table definitions, sample data and desired results.  Are you trying to determine which studies have more than a single course associated with it?

Comment: No, It must show a course name with at least two students enrolled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your comment correctly, then you just need to `join` the tables together and use a single `group by` with `having`:

```
select c.course_id, c.name
from course c
   join studies s on c.course_id = s.course_id
group by c.course_id, c.name
having count(s.course_id) > 1
```

Comment: and what's with 'c' and 's', what're these?